# Parse Croatian Date string into DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, culture

I have the following string from WebService `"1.4.2013. 0:00:00"`.
I want to get `DateTime` object from that `string`.
What I have tried so far:

```
string d = "1.4.2013. 00:00:00";
 DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR"));

DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d",new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It tells me that

> string is not recognized as valid dateTime string.

I want to solve this without string parsing eg: removing the dot after the year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `"d"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) uses [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) of supplied culture. Since you use `DateTime.ParseExact`, format and string should match *exactly*.

But`hr-HR` culture's [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern is `d.M.yyyy.` and this clearly doesn't match with your string. It doesn't match with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) either.

However, this format is a standard date and time format for `hr-HR` culture, so you can use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) directly like;

```
string d = "1.4.2013. 00:00:00";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(d, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hr-HR"));
// 01/04/2013 00:00:00
```

Your string matches [The `"G"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) of `hr-HR` culture which based on combination of `ShortDatePattern` and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) properties as `d.M.yyyy. H:mm:ss`.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d.M.yyyy. HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
solves my problem, your answer however is correct but in DotNet 3.5 I dont see (dot) . after year for hr-HR CultureInfo. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `G` as format specifier. The "G" standard format specifier represents a combination of the short date ("d") and long time ("T") patterns, separated by a space.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralDateLongTime)

```
string d = "1.4.2013. 00:00:00";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "G",new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
string date = "1.4.2013. 00:00:00";
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR");

DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(date, ci);
```

As Soner said, you tried to use the short date pattern, which does not contain any time information, therfore the `ParseExact` fails. Using `Parse` lets the method figure out which format to use.

If you want to use `ParseExact` (e.g. for [performance reasons](http://blog.joachim.at/?p=42)) you can use the one of the following (equivalent) statements:

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d.M.yyyy. HH:mm:ss", ci);
```

or

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "G", ci);
```